# Comma errors while using vim-syntastic plugin

Tags: python, vim, terminal, vim-syntastic

When saving python files, vim-syntactic starts debugging and raises syntax errors (specifically commas), whether its in a list, dictionary, tuple etc. Here is an image after saving python file.

[image]

Comment: you forgot the image...

Comment: @HelderSepu thanks. Not sure why it didn't save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim-Syntactic throws syntax errors when you don't add a space after commas.

```
√ animals = set(['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'])  # no errors
x animals = set(['cat','dog','mouse'])  # errors
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your code, that is not valid syntax, I guess you are very new to python...

An object is declared using the {} 
Here is how an object looks like:

```
farm_animals = {"sheep":"big", "cow":"huge"}
print(farm_animals)
```

You can try it out online on some other editor:
http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_UotVM3f1Pw_0.py

Comment: @ HelderSepu WOW. Thanks for catching that. I read somewhere that I can create sets using curly brackets and if the items are separated like a list i.e. commas, then it'll interpret it as a set. Im a fan of vim but ill check codeskulptor out. Thanks again :)

Comment: @plutonium244 Dont forget to +1 ...and mark as the answer if it solves your problem